# TCPDF unsharp text

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

When using TCPDF to generate PDF-files for invoices, when printed the text is a bit unsharp.
This is regardless of the font I'm using.

Is there a way to improve the settings that text is much sharper?

The DPI doesn't seem to be changeable, when tried it pulls the page out of it's bounds.

Comment: Can you post some of your sample codes? Generated PDF texts should be vector, thus unsharp text should not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPI Shouldn't be the problem since text is a vectorized object. Make sure you open it a in a decent PDF viewer. I tend to have some basic pdf problems in FireFox defaults' viewer. Which are perfectly fine when printed or openened in Adobe Reader.

Have you tried the default fonts of TCPDF?

Comment: I've tried the default fonts, parsed some Windows-TTF files (Arial etc.) as fonts, all the same, but now when I print monochrome the text is a lot sharper. I also print in Adobe Reader.

Comment: try using a slightly different color on the object. Can you share an example PDF?